# Php can not be found on MSYS2

Tags: php, msys, msys2

I am using Msys2 on windows10

```
$ pacman -Sl | grep 'pacman '
msys pacman 5.2.1-6 [インストール済み]
```

Then,I tried to install php.

```
$pacman -S php

error: can't find target. : php
```

There is no package php.

```
$ pacman -Ss php
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-doxygen 1.8.17-1
    A documentation system for C++, C, Java, IDL and PHP (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-doxygen 1.8.17-1
    A documentation system for C++, C, Java, IDL and PHP (mingw-w64)
msys/doxygen 1.8.17-1
    A documentation system for C++, C, Java, IDL and PHP
```

I guess I should add some php repository???

How can I install the php??

Comment: msys2 does not have a php package. You may have to build it from source.

Comment: I see.. I will try another way

Answer (score 0):

You can call windows executables from msys2. Install PHP for windows, add it to path, and use in msys2.